# Login error 401 while making put request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to post a videoId in a youtube playlist using youtube api in python. Below is my code,

```
import json
from apiclient.discovery import build
import requests
post_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems"
payload = {
    'key':"*******",
    'part':'snippet',
    'playlistId':'****',
    'videoId':'****'
}

r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.text)
```

But now I keep getting below error,

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I've tried getting data by GET request in similar way and I was successful in that. What is wrong with this then?

Comment: The call requires an `Authorization` header to be set. Most likely it has to contain an OAuth token. Many GET calks to youtube can be done without authorization.

Comment: oh, so it won't work by passing just the api_key?

Answer (score 0):

401 means Unauthorized.

So, you need to pass authentication details.

Examples:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#examples

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets

Comment: I'm trying to pass authorisation in the form of API_KEY, will that won't work?